# HTML5 video: Shorten the amount of time controls take to hide themselves

Tags: html, video

This may well be a long-shot (I suspect some of the feature requests in the project I'm working on might be 'bordering on' pedantic) but is there a simple way - that doesn't involve designing a javascript video player - to lower the amount of time the html5 video player progress bar takes to disappear, once the mouse stops moving?

Yes, you read me right.

I guess what I'm hoping for is, say, an html attribute in the video tag that can be set to a certain amount of milliseconds, or something... I haven't been able to find anything, so I'm guessing the answer is 'no'.

Actually I'm hoping the answer is a straight 'no', but unfortunately I have to ask.

Any help, either way, much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: if you are using the standard HTML5 `<video>` element then it's down to the browser and you have no control. You could always go down the path of building your own overlay / controls, but ...